# Creating bitmap in C - How to write /r /n as 1 byte?

Tags: c, bitmap

I'm trying to create bitmap in C. Firstly what i want to do is copy header and all pixels data from other bitmap file. The problem is with number '10', which when i'm reading it's just 1 byte, but when i write it's 2 bytes. I know about /r /n things, but how for example Paint can save it as 1 char?

I'm reading header in this way:

```
unsigned char* header = malloc(54);
fread(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, file);
```

and writing in this way:

```
fwrite(img->fileHeader, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, file);
```

Comment: you have to open your stream with `ios::binary` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ios::binary` flag when dealing with non-text files, always:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

If you're using Windows and not specifying the `ios::binary` flag when opening your streams here what happens:

`13 10` sequences are converted to `10` when reading: corrupt data in memory. If the data is binary in the first place you'd be unlucky to get those sequences but it can happen

`10` is converted to `13 10` (CR+LF) when writing. That is more likely to happen and corrupts your output file.

Note: even if it's corrupt, reading as text and writing back as binary fixes the corruption (or replace `13 10` by `10`)